# HDInsight: Hive Metastore - Schema version 2.1.2?

Tags: azure-hdinsight, hive-metastore

I have a hive metastore setup on an Azure SQL Database that is used by HDInsight clusters. When I go into the cluster and use the schematool to verify versions, it returns Hive Distribution 1.2.1 and Metastore schema version 2.1.2.

This becomes troublesome when I try to connect to this metastore using databricks, which returns errors saying that 2.1.2 is not a valid metastore schema version. I try substituting the version with 2.1.1 or 2.1.0 and it errors out as well. I've tried looking at official distributions from apache (https://hive.apache.org/downloads.html) and don't see it listed.

Has anyone else come across this error? Am I missing something or is this a bug in HDInsight's setting up of the metastore?

Comment: You need to check these-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/metastores/external-hive-metastore  and https://www.linkconsulting.com/blog/azure-databricks-and-azure-hdinsight-hive-integration/

Comment: Where is your schematool binary located? i am using hdinsight as well working on a metastore migration from 2.1 to 3.1 but i can't find the schematool command.

Comment: If I recall it was likely nested under the /etc/hive/ folder on the cluster itself. I've since moved jobs so haven't needed to do this in a long time. I know it's somewhere in the cluster by default. Good luck on your migration.